# In macOS (Sonoma) are notifications supposed to stay on the screen when the Notifications Center slides off the screen?

Tags: macos, notifications

I'd swear notifications used to slide in and out along with the widgets when you clicked on the time on the right edge of the menu bar in OS X. Am I missing something?

I can include screenshots if I need clarification on what I am asking.

Comment: Please include those screenshots, I don't really see what you mean

Comment: I talked to Apple Support. This was a change in moving from Ventura to Sonoma. The notifications used to slide away when the Notification Center was closed, and now they stay on the screen, blocking everything.

I am filing a fix with Apple to move the functionality back to how it was.

I'll add the screenshots if I can figure out how to upload them without much trouble.

Comment: Okay. Weirdly enough, I cannot replicate the issue. Both when I try clicking time and date or sliding from the right side of my trackpad, the notifications go away with the Notification Centre.

Comment: I've been reverse engineering macOS for several months now and I now know most of what I need to.

Thank you to everyone who helped me.

Comment: Well I guess you could post an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I talked to Apple Support. This was a change in moving from Ventura to Sonoma. The notifications used to slide away when the Notification Center was closed, and now they stay on the screen, blocking everything. I am filing a fix with Apple to move the functionality back to how it was. I'll add the screenshots if I can figure out how to upload them without much trouble. –

Before closing, the notifications were there as they were:

[image]

After closing the Notification Center, they are still there in Sonoma. They were not in Ventura:

[image]

If you work with the Apple macOS (OS X) team, please file this as a bug in Sonoma and note here that this has been filed as a bug so I can quit trying to let Apple know about it. Thank you.

-Todd B, Co-founder, Fritter Inc.